# Неправильно открываются docx файлы

Tags: php, office

Есть свежая самописная система документооборота (HTML+PHP+MySQL).
При клике на *.doc - файлы вызывают окно открытия файла, в нём можно и сохранить файл. Всё, как надо.
Но стоит прибегнуть к "любимому" новому формату Office - docx, pptx, xlsx, как сразу же всё ломается!
Файлы открываются, как на просмотр в коммандере! Т.е. открывается не файл, а вся его внутренняя структура.

### Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Я про web-сервер и файлы залитые через PHP на web-сервер.
Для дальнейшего скачивания их пользователями.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть ответ на англ версии: [Вот ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487365/http-header-for-downloading-microsoft-word-and-excel-files)

В качестве короткой выжимки могу подсказать следующее:

*.docx и *.xlsx для Веб-сервера являются типом `application/zip`. Именно из-за этого файл предлагается открыть как архив, используя связанную программу.

При отдаче файла стоит менять заголовки ответа на `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');`.

Если файлы отдаются Веб-сервером без обработки PHP скриптами, то можно прописать в .htaccess `AddType application/octet-stream .docx`. Нужно поменять расширение файла, если используется не только docx.

Comment: Спасибо! А позже нашёл ещё и это http://www.oddler.ru/i/315

Answer (score 0):

Когда браузер получает файл, ему нужно решить, что с этим файлом делать. Тут на помощь приходят (как минимум) две характеристики ответа сервера

- `Content-Type` - тип содержимого. Если браузер не может открыть это содержимое, то он предложит его скачать. Очевидно, с `docx` ему кажется, что он это сделать в силах.
- `Content-Disposition` - вот это уже является настоящей рекомендацией к обращению с файлом. Если стоит значение `inline` (насколько понимаю, значение по умолчанию) - значит, этот документ можно отображать, `attachment` - надо скачивать. Конечно же, нужен `attachment`.

В `Content-Disposition` также отдается имя файла, поэтому финальный спасительный вызов будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
header(sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="%s"', $filename));
```

Имейте в виду, что для русскоязычных названий может потребоваться дополнительная магия. Однако никто вам не запрещает просто создавать файлы на диске и перенаправлять пользователя на них, оставляя всю головную боль веб-серверу. Если же это и есть текущий случай, то нужно настроить сервер согласно рекомендациям в соседнем ответе или аналогичным способом принудить отдавать `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Answer (score -3):

Потому как эти файлы представляют из себя архивы и твоя система считает их архивами, соответственно для их просмотра и выбирает соответственную программую. Необходимо в системных настройках указать чем их открывать по-умолчанию

Comment: Глупости вы говорите: система при открытии файла двойным кликом не смотрит на содержимое, она ищет информацию в реестре основываясь только на расширении файла. Можете переименовать любой ZIP в *.dumb и проверить.

Comment: это если всё правильно прописано.

Comment: А если не прописано - система спросит чем открыть.

Comment: Дак значит что-то прописано, раз система не спрашивает.

Comment: Может и прописано, но тогда системе тем более поперек на содержимое, что я и пытаюсь донести.

Comment: @Вадим вы вообще про что?
Я-то про web-сервер и файлы залитые через PHP на web-сервер.
А потом пользователи их скачивают.

Comment: Скачивет браузером? в в раузере есть вопрос либо сохранить, либо открыть с помощью. и есть галочка запомнить действие. после скачивания, клик по файлу тоже позволяет открывать с вопросом или без. достаточно сделать однажды  неправильно и запомнить будет такой эффект. это как один из наиболее вероятных вариантов.

Comment: @Вадим вы наверное действительно не представляете о чём я...
Вы программист? Вы загрузку файлов на сервер писали?
GrayHoax уже сполна ответил.
И вот вам на заметку про что я - http://www.oddler.ru/i/315